# How to do big files comparing in Big data platform?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

Here are some big files coming in a day, not very frequent, 2-3 every single day, and they are converted into JSON format.

The file's content looks like:

```
[
    {
        "spa_ref_data": {
            "approval_action": "New",
            "spa_ref_no": "6500781413",
            "begin_date": null,
            "end_date": "20191009",
            "doc_file_name": "LEN_SPA_6500781413.json",
            "LEN_V": "v1",
            "version_no": null,
            "spa_ref_id": null,
            "spa_ref_notes": "MC00020544",
            "vend_code": "LEN"
        },
        "cust_data": [
            {
                "cust_name": null,
                "cust_no": null,
                "cust_type": "E",
                "state": null,
                "country": null
            },
            {
                "cust_name": null,
                "cust_no": null,
                "cust_type": "C",
                "state": null,
                "country": null
            }
        ],
        "product_data": [
            {
                "mfg_partno": "40AH0135US",
                "std_price": null,
                "rebate_amt": "180",
                "max_spa_qty": null,
                "rebate_type": null,
                "min_spa_qty": null,
                "min_cust_qty": null,
                "max_cust_qty": null,
                "begin_date": "20180608",
                "end_date": null
            },
            {
                "mfg_partno": "40AJ0135US",
                "std_price": null,
                "rebate_amt": "210",
                "max_spa_qty": null,
                "rebate_type": null,
                "min_spa_qty": null,
                "min_cust_qty": null,
                "max_cust_qty": null,
                "begin_date": "20180608",
                "end_date": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "spa_ref_data": {
            "approval_action": "New",
            "spa_ref_no": "5309745006",
            "begin_date": null,
            "end_date": "20190426",
            "doc_file_name": "LEN_SPA_5309745006.json",
            "LEN_V": "v1",
            "version_no": null,
            "spa_ref_id": null,
            "spa_ref_notes": "MC00020101",
            "vend_code": "LEN"
        },
        "cust_data": [
            {
                "cust_name": null,
                "cust_no": null,
                "cust_type": "E",
                "state": null,
                "country": null
            },
            {
                "cust_name": null,
                "cust_no": null,
                "cust_type": "C",
                "state": null,
                "country": null
            }
        ],
        "product_data": [
            {
                "mfg_partno": "10M8S0HU00",
                "std_price": null,
                "rebate_amt": "698",
                "max_spa_qty": null,
                "rebate_type": null,
                "min_spa_qty": null,
                "min_cust_qty": null,
                "max_cust_qty": null,
                "begin_date": "20180405",
                "end_date": null
            },
            {
                "mfg_partno": "20K5S0CM00",
                "std_price": null,
                "rebate_amt": "1083",
                "max_spa_qty": null,
                "rebate_type": null,
                "min_spa_qty": null,
                "min_cust_qty": null,
                "max_cust_qty": null,
                "begin_date": "20180405",
                "end_date": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is a mock data file.In fact, it is a array with length 30000+.

My target is to compare the coming one with the latest one. And get the changed data.

The leader says I must use the big data techs. And the performance must be good.

We use Apache NIFI and hadoop big data tools to do it.

Is there some advice ?

Comment: are you containerising any of the data are you load them?

Comment: It's unclear what your expected output is... If the performance "must be good", use a proper document database, not Hadoop

Comment: Also, how big are your files really? Array with 30000+ elements or even 100000 elements could easily fit into RAM => no special big data tools needed. Of course you can use them, but also consider normal data analysis frameworks (or code yourself if needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use ExecuteScript processor with js scrpit to compare jsons. It works fast. Also you can split your big array json with SplitRecord processor and compare each one by executeScript proccessor. It also works good.